# catkin_make does not add package to /opt/ros/noetic

Tags: catkin-make, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Info:**

- ROS Distro: noetic
- OS: Ubuntu Server 20.04.5 LTS
- Architecture: ARM64 (raspberry pi 4B 8GB)

I am following [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage) on how to create a simple ROS package. I think all has worked up until the 4th stage of the process. When I cd into `~/catkin_ws` then do `catkin_make` this is the output:

```
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -14" in "home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build"
####
```

Sourcing it using `. ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` (I have also tried `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`)

Then, when I try to use `rospack` to locate the package with `rospack find <package name>` it cannot be found. I also know the package has been added to my `/home/ubuntu/noetic/<package name>` including the `package.xml` file containing the dependencies I added etc.

I'm unsure if this is helpful information, but within the `/opt/ros/noetic/` directory there is no `devel` directory. Does this mean that the `catkin_make` is potentially failing but not telling me?

What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/408261/catkin_make-does-not-add-package-to-/opt/ros/noetic/) by [meropis](https://answers.ros.org/users/121372/meropis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> catkin_make does not add package to /opt/ros/noetic

that's correct.

It's not supposed to.

A `catkin_make` invocation only manages the workspace the command is invoked in. It will not create, update nor delete any files in any other workspaces.

> When I cd into `~/catkin_ws` then do `catkin_make` this is the output:
>
> ```
> ####
> ```

```
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -14" in "home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build"
####
```

if that's the only output, it's likely your package is either:

- not a package (ie: doesn't contain the required `package.xml` or `CMakeList.txt`), or
- not in the right directory (ie: the `src` space of the workspace)

A `catkin_make` invocation on a workspace with a package in it should result in much more logging output.

If Catkin doesn't actually build any packages, it's to be expected `rospack` can't `find` it either.

> I also know the package has been added to my `/home/ubuntu/noetic/<package name>` [..]

could you clarify what you mean by this? That directory would not have any special meaning to `catkin_make`, so I'm not sure what you're trying to say.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [meropis](https://answers.ros.org/users/121372/meropis/) on 2022-10-21**:
I think my package is not in the right place. I’ll try putting it into the /src directory and report back. In terms of what I meant by the package location, thats where it was created for me. I think this is my issue and the above will solve it. Update - it worked. Thank you for your assistance.